# If you set a report access permission to everyone, includes anonymous, can it be viewed publicly?

Tags: civievent, permissions, reports

Wordpress - Civi 5.48

I created an event report and I want it so anyone can view who is attending by using the link.

I figured out the link part - https://example.org/civicrm/report/instance/44/

I gave "CiviReport: access CiviReport" permission to anonymous user and changed permission on the report itself, but the results don't actually appear.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've been down this road and reports do not show on the front-end. Another reason for Search Kit and making a display.

Comment: Are you saying this is a need or that you can make a publicly accessible display in search kit?

Comment: Yeah you can make an event participant display and include the fields you want.

Comment: Is there documentation on this somewhere?

Comment: this has just been written and may give you some useful hints https://lab.civicrm.org/alainb/user-en/-/blob/searchkit-otterlo-sprint/docs/searching/searchkit/case-upcoming-events.md

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting on Events for "Participant Listing"

> To allow users to see a listing of participants, set this field to 'Name' (list names only), 'Name and Email', or 'Name, Status and Register Date'. You will need to set Access Control permissions to include 'view event participants' for any Roles you want to access this listing. After adding your event, create links to the listing page by copying the URL provided in the 'Participant Listing' section of the Configure Event page.

Does that not suffice?

Comment: We would want to see Employer, Job Title and a Custom Field. We also only want people with the link to see who is attending, not everyone.